# I am using Jenkins CI, and I am trying to set up the ability to send emails. However I am unable to connect to the SMTP host

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp, gmail

I am unable to connect to a SMTP host using the E-mail Notification abilities in Jenkins. I believe I have everything set up correctly. This is my configuration:

SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com

Default user e-mail suffix: @gmail.com

Use SMTP Authentication: checked User

Name: myUsername@gmail.com Password: myGmailPassword

Use SSL: checked SMTP Port: 465

Reply-To Address: NOREPLY@gmail.com Charset: UTF-8

I have disabled any antivirus and firewalls on the machine that Jenkins is running on. This is the error I am running into:

```
Failed to send out e-mail
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:522)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:120)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:728)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:858)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:631)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:225)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:286)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:205)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
... 63 more
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) or [configure "less secure apps"](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) in gmail.

Comment: The problem occurs earlier than all TLS or authentication stuff, it doesn't seem to be DNS related either. It's just a timeout, therefore I would assume some network/firewall problems. Usually I try to telnet the port from the same host and user: telnet smtp.gmail.com 465. Here it works and I get the following response:
"Trying 173.194.65.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'." If it blocks after emitting "Trying 173.194.65.108..." then your problem is probably not related to Jenkins.

Comment: This might be helpful, take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512948/configuring-jenkins-email-notification-with-gmail/36172630#36172630