# Error setting up email configurations in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am getting `Null pointer exception` while configuring email notification in Jenkins.

I have made the required changes on gmail account.
Have followed the steps exactly, but I still get below error when I test my configuration:

> Test configuration
>   ERROR
>   A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has happened.

Stack trace

Comment: This error is at configuration or at using the email ext?

Comment: I get this error,when I test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512948/configuring-jenkins-email-notification-with-gmail):

> The latest mailer plugin version 1.24 has a bug, which causes test
>   configuration failure(authentication required) even if you have the
>   correct configuration. Download the 1.23 (.hpi file) version from
>   Official website, then upload it from manage plugin->advanced. Restart
>   jenkins, it should work well.
>
> Only need to enable the less secure app access, there is no need to
>   open 2-step verification.

If that is your problem go to the answer from tw Zhang and give a vote. I only would add that I have tried with plugin 1.25 and also fails

Comment: I upgraded mailer version and it worked for me.Thanks for your help.