# Jenkins email notification with gmail smtp

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp, gmail

Trying to send email using Jenkins- using the email notification plugin, using ssl option.

Initially was getting bad id/pwd error-   also got login blocked alert emails from google.
So **enabled the less secure apps**. The error changed to javax.mail.**AuthenticationFailedException**: 534-5.7.14

I do not have 2-step auth enabled in gmail. 
[Read a couple of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512948/configuring-jenkins-email-notification-with-gmail/36172630#36172630) here suggesting - need to use  2-step auth method with gmail - is that the way to go?

**How do I install older plugin?**
I downloaded the older Mailer plugin 1.23 (wget) it is a .hpi file. But in my plug folder only has jpi files. What it is supposed to be?
Do I just go to the console and uninstall the current plugin and just copy this hpi file to /plugins folder?

Able to install the .hpi finally
Advanced installation
The Update Center only allows the installation of the most recently released version of a plugin. In cases where an older release of the plugin is desired, a Jenkins administrator can download an older .hpi archive and manually install that on the Jenkins master.

From the web UI
Assuming a .hpi file has been downloaded, a logged-in Jenkins administrator may upload the file from within the web UI:

Navigate to the Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins page in the web UI.

Click on the Advanced tab.

Choose the .hpi file under the Upload Plugin section.

[Upload the plugin file.](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/)

After uploading .hpi from local system using the GUI) - the Mailer plugin version shows the new older `Mailer version 1.23`. But you have to reconfigure it.

**But still same error:**
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14

support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 [q128sm12098788pga.24 - gsmtp](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754). checking the google support link -   **I think am doing everything as suggested**

Comment: Yes, two-step authentication should work. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048152/361089) provides the relevant details.

Comment: Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57621730/361089) answer in case you're using latest version of `Mailer` plugin. You might need to downgrade it.

Comment: How do install older plugin - check comments on main post.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588907/361089) answer tells you how to install plugin using GUI. As far as extension name is concerned, both should work. `.jpi` is the newer extension name that Jenkins uses.

Comment: I did update the plugin to 2.63. But still get same error : javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvg
534-5.7.14 ltD9ulyOk3OirXJr3Eb33H-23yEt-Dp3JurtOOlf9dYZWYy8OLk89JQLKLSHSEi636wWxl
534-5.7.14 xBqpyyXWkIsiF3pxgoAw8wm8I1elGodh63iz8dViY0OIC_qWB3h1SF1ciCWKlY> Please
534-5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q128sm12098788pga.24 - gsmtp.    checking the google support link - I am doing everything as suggested.

Comment: I still have "allow less secure apps login".  But one difference I noticed now is - when I did not have this on earlier - I was getting "blocked" alerts from Google, they had stopped when I enabled. But now once again I am getting blocked alerts from google.

Comment: Tried using yahoo smtp it came up with its own error: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.  This is totally wheird. Did not get any security alerts in yahoo

Comment: What version of `Mailer` plugin do you have? The link i suggested in my second comment recommends to downgrade `Mailer` plugin to version `1.23`.

Comment: I have Mailer plugin 1.23 now.  With Google smtp I get javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs.. With Yahoo smtp I get: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts. In yahoo I am using email -it does not have 2-fac on.  I can see these errors on the Jenkins console - test email itself

Comment: I tried this with **outlook smtp** also - got errors:  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [MWHPR02CA0014.namprd02.prod.o