# How to configure Jenkins email notification with gmail

Tags: jenkins, gmail

I have Jenkins 2.332.3 installed on my EC2 Ubuntu 20.04 instance, and I'm trying to configure email notification with gmail.

I have Email Extension Plugin 2.88 installed

Extended E-mail Notification:

```
SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP port: 465
Credentials: <user_id>@gmail.com/<password>
Use SSL: enabled
Use TSL: disabled
```

E-mail Notification:

```
SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
Use SMTP Authentication:
User Name: <user_ID>@gmail.com
Password: <password>
Use SSL: enabled
Use TSL: disabled
SMTP Port: 465
```

I can no longer enable "Less secure app access" for the google/gmail account, as Google no longer makes this setting available.  And I do not have 2FA turned on for the google/gmail account.

When I select "Test configuration", I receive the following error:

> Failed to send out e-mail
>
> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and
> Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
> a12-20020a02940c000000b0032b3a781766sm6949102jai.42 - gsmtp
>
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
> at
> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
> at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)     at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)  at
> javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)  at
> javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)    at
> javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
> hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:728)    at
> java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
> at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:398)
> at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:410)
> at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:78)
> at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
> at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:208)    at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:141)
> at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
> at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
> at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)  at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)  at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:289)    at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
> at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)  at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)  at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)  at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
> at
> hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
> at
> jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:81)
> at
> hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
> at
> jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
> at
> hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
> at
> hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:154)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
> at
> jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
> at
> hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
> at
> jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
> at
> hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
> at
> hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
> at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)     at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at
> hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at
> org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at
> jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)  at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
> at
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512948/configuring-jenkins-email-notification-with-gmail  at least two solutions here will work for your specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The less Secure App option was deprecated and disabled on 30th May 2022. Instead, you can use an App password. Here instead of using your account password, you should be able to generate an app-specific password. Refer [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip!  Before adding the App password, I did have to enable 2FA for the account.  After enabling 2FA, and adding the App password, I copied the App password to my Jenkins email configuration, tested the email configuration, and received the email is no issues.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, 2FA is mandatory to generate App passwords.